# You can only post once every 40 minutes

Tags: discussion

In both https://dba.stackexchange.com/ & https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/, I tried to post a new question. After I clicked **Post your question**, the system said `A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.` **and did not allow me to post the question**. Now after I edited the question title and tried to post the question, it says `You can only post once every 40 minutes.`

Is it a bug or it is something done on purpose? If that is done on purpose, do I have to keep this question open on a tab for the next 40 mins. Seriously...?

Atleast it doesn't happen on StackOverflow

**Edit**

Even I waited for 40 mins to post this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose this happened just after posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63559411/4751173), so that's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The 40 minutes limit is applied **across the network**, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232):

> #### Asking
>
> - Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/4751173) (This applies to the user's IP address, *not* their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, [they may not be limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341711/295232).)

One of the reasons for this is to prevent users from posting the same question on multiple sites; while this might give you an answer quicker, it also leads to fragmentation. Please remember that you're not only asking for yourself, but also for future users with the same problem. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/295232) for more details.

Comment: It might not apply to Meta, I'm not sure about it. It could also be (but it's not likely) that somebody else on the same IP address posted a question somewhere in the network.

Comment: I accidentally asked the same question (the one that you highlighted) on meta.dba and deleted it instantly on realizing that the question should not go to meta. Then I tried to repost it on DBA which led to the error. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5):

This is documented on main meta in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)
:

> ### Asking
>
> - Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's
>   IP address, *not* their account. If the user shares that IP with other
>   users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question
>   anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question
>   from a different IP address, [they may not be
>   limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341711/377214).)
>
>   [image: Question limit - You can only post once every 40 minutes]
>
>   - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes. Some of these per-site limits do
>     also check the account, not just the IP address.
>   - While the limit is waived for users with 125+ reputation on a given site, questions posted on sites where one has 125+ reputation
>     still count toward the rate limit for sites where one doesn't. For
>     instance, if you ask a question on a site where you have 150 rep, you
>     can't ask another question on a site where you have only 100 rep for
>     the next 40 minutes; however, you can ask them in reverse order
>     immediately (first on the 100-rep site, then on the 150-rep site).